# Problem with metadata on pool.pm

Tags: nft, native-assets, minting, metadata

I am having some trouble with metadata for NFT I am minting.

This is the asset on pool.pm:
https://pool.pm/asset1q6fku9qrfld526pfdm746qu3j7wtgvuh5xet9u

And again on adaptors.org:
https://adapools.org/transactions/3bec2e04ecf374d8d341f6d4ef38c2b1b70b1817cb2e6a9fa197b2aea7dd8de2/metadata

When viewing the asset on pool.pm it shows an error:

```
Error:
Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `721`
```

But viewing it on adapools.org show that 721 tag is there.

And this is the actual metadata submitted in the transaction. What am I doing wrong here? And why is it pool.pm showing an error?

```
{
  "721": {
    "b767134d5185d7d7be2234855cc732c8b3b42d8b956b84244c83015c": {
      "TestNFT5": {
        "Name": "TestNFT #5",
        "Collection": "Multi-asset minting",
        "Description": "Used for testing multi-asset minting",
        "Mythic": "True",
        "Mythic Name": "Ancient",
        "Wizard Type": "Alcemist",
        "Ring Name": "Vollzabar",
        "mediaType": "image/jpg",
        "image": "ipfs://QmXEyaE9GQJ2Qbgzozjfb23drA5jaU9qXJu8jNPPxysZhu"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: Naturally, I have validated metadata before minting using https://pool.pm/test/metadata and no errors were shown.

Comment: pool.pm answers a similar issue - see if there are some useful pointers there: https://forum.cardano.org/t/problem-in-displaying-nft-on-pool-pm-after-minting/90381/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong policy ID in your metadata.

This is your mint trx https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/3bec2e04ecf374d8d341f6d4ef38c2b1b70b1817cb2e6a9fa197b2aea7dd8de2?tab=metadata

The actual policy Id of your asset is `abd58940b13f956ca5450786f14276204cf19b8b62105dc83b32cc64` and your metadata has `b767134d5185d7d7be2234855cc732c8b3b42d8b956b84244c83015c`

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed my code and can see that I accidentally used minting hash instead of policy id. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!